# Can't see the design GUI on VS2010 after load and saved changes using bland

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have some project that i created using VS2010.
In some part of the develop - I opened the project using the microsoft Bland.
I made some changes and i saved the project in the bland.

But now, when i open the project using the VS2010 i can't see the design gui.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild it

Comment: tried already - dont work ..

Comment: close vs , open in blend and rebuild

Comment: Some things like `ResourceDictionary` may not show up in the Design view. Is that your case? Also, can you open it in Blend?